# React Native Expo run in webview resize app

Tags: react-native, expo

When using expo to run react native and running in a web browser, the app takes up the entire screen. How do I make it so that the app can resize and look like a phone screen? I tried opening f12, but there's no button on the top right that allows me to resize the view. [Here is a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVIsX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### if your question is how to resize your browser? you can follow this.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much.